# After pulse Generate clock that last for 10 clock cycles

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to create a clock that only last 10 clock cycles from a 100 MHz signal. The clock will get enabled from a pulse signal.

-Every time the pulse signal goes to 1 clock2 follows 100 MHz clock1 for 10 cycles

- I am working in VHDL

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that a 100 MHz clock is given as an input?

Assuming it is, a small state machine and a counter would be a good way to approach this. The state machine could have 2 states: *idle* and *count*. The next state logic would change the state from *idle* to *count* if the pulse signal is high. While in the count state the counter will increment and when the counter reaches ten, the state will move back to *idle*. The output logic will forward the clock signal to the output when in the *count* state. When in *idle* the output will be '0'.

For more information on making a state machine: [How to implement state machines in VHDL](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-implement-state-machines-in-vhdl.html)

For more information on making a counter: [Counters in VHDL](http://quartushelp.altera.com/11.1/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_pro_counters.htm)

clock_input is the 100 MHz clock that is an input and clock_generated is the output.

The output logic will involve a multiplexer:

```
clock_generated <= clock_input when state=count else '0';
```

Comment: That would be a gated clock which is probably not what you really need. Why not generate an internal enable signal for 10 cycles and use that in the following logic, that would be much easier to handle in the synthesis flow...

Comment: I definitely agree, clock signals should not be gated. An enable signal would be a better option.

Comment: You could do something like this: `enable <= '1' when state=count else '0';`